# Etymology of fatuous

Tags: etymology

*Fatuous* means stupid.

Does its etymology relate to *fat*? Are *fat* and *stupid* correlated?

Comment: This is general reference. A dictionary would give you both words' etymologies.

Comment: Do not guess, ask a dictionary.

Comment: Since etymonline lists fatuous's etymology as "of uncertain origin", I think it's a legitimate question that can be answered with something more than just copying the dictionary's etymology.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan the origin of fatuous is not uncertain - it comes from the Latin word *fatuus*.  *Fatuus* is of uncertain origin. That's not the same thing. Since the origin of *fat* is very different, it's quite clear that the two are unrelated.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan +1. This same question possessed me.

Answer (score 6):

It seems unlikely. Etymonline links [fatuous](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fatuous&allowed_in_frame=0) to

> **Latin** fatuus "foolish, insipid, silly;"

while [fat](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fat&allowed_in_frame=0) hails from

> **Old English** fætt "fat, fatted, plump, obese," originally a contracted past participle of fættian "to cram, stuff," from **Proto-Germanic** *faitaz "fat"

With one word hailing from Latin while the other from Proto-Germanic, it seems unlikely they have a shared origin.

Comment: In fact (if the link with _fatuus_ is indeed correct), they cannot have a shared origin, unless Latin borrowed the word from Germanic, which does not seem likely. As the native Latin word _pinguis_ ‘fat’ (from the same root) shows, the Latin form should have been _*patuus_ if anything (and an a in the first syllable would be very hard to account for as well). Sadly, etymonline does not mention my favourite cognate with ‘fat’, which is ***Ireland*** (the fat/fertile land).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely from Latin, it has the same meaning of several similar words in neo-Latin languages.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but *substantiated* answers are preferred on this site, so as to distinguish them from mere opinions. Would you please supplement your answer with links, references, examples, etc. to support it.